# Ionic 2 and github

Tags: github, ionic2, push, pull

I have committed a tabs app project to a classroom repo set up by our lecturer.

I changed my mind then and want to start with a blank app.

Now I seem to have two `master` branches and need to delete the first.
The push triggers the following error message:

```
error-- ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx/2nd-year-software-ionic-2-assignment-xxxxxxxx.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How can I get past that error message?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is force the push:

```
git push --force -u origin master
```

That will replace the history of the remote master by the one you have locally.